# how to configure Tomcat manager on each instance?

Tags: tomcat

I got Tomcat Instance running and as well the root with Tomcat manager. I am following the following tutorial to configure Tomcat manager on my new Tomcat instance:
http://grokandroll.com/tomcat/configurating-tomcat-manager.html

After configuring and pointing to www.website.com:8081/manager i got nothing....blank, no errors,no login...and nothing in Logs. my app runs at www.website.com:8081/sample

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this?

p.s. manager.xml

```
   <Context path="/manager"          
      docBase="/usr/local/mywebbase/webapps/manager"        
      debug="0"     
      privileged="true">      

   <ResourceLink name="users"      
      global="UserDatabase"       
      type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"/>      
      <!--<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"           allow="127.0.0.1,192.168.100.100"/>-->          

    </Context>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try going to www.website.com:8081/manager/html.

Comment: Thank you mindas for replaying. I tried and the same thing - blank no errors screen

Comment: Check Tomcat startup logs and see if message about manager app being deployed appears.

Comment: Thank you. it certainly looks that way. Any other ideas?

Comment: here is part of the log:INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.32
Feb 13, 2011 3:09:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor host-manager.xml
Feb 13, 2011 3:09:18 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor manager.xml
Feb 13, 2011 3:09:18 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory ROOT

Comment: Thank you for looking into this